# Is it possible to get the which "where" condition is matched in Vespa.ai?

Tags: java, elasticsearch, bigdata, vespa

I have a use case where I need to find out which "where" condition of the query is matched to get the result if we provided multiple conditions.

for example-

we have organization data, where we have employee name, city, technology and hobbies.

Now we have 3 conditions that are-
1. we need to get the records where the city is FOO_CITY.
2. we need to get the records where the technology is FOO_TECH.
3. we need to get the records where the hobby is FOO_BLOG.

when we write the query we get the output rows which satisfies these condition but I need to find out which condition is satisfied from all the above three.

Comment: You mean your condition is `1 OR 2 OR 3`?

Comment: @M.Prokhorov yes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can ask Vespa to produce summary rank features which you can consume in your middle tier or in a searcher plugin.

See https://docs.vespa.ai/documentation/ranking.html.

Set of built in rank features https://docs.vespa.ai/documentation/reference/rank-features.html

Given that we have 3 fields, city, technology and hobby:

```
rank-profile what-matched-my-query {
    first-phase {
       expression: something 
     }
    summary-features {
      matches(city)
      matches(technology)
      matches(hobby)
    }
}
```

/search/?yql=s..;&ranking=what-matched-my-query